# How can I fix this MySQL error?

Tags: php, mysql

Fatal error: SQL in /home/trilocus/public_html/database/characters.php on line 140

Here is line 140:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, name FROM npcs LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage WHERE name LIKE $search";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, name FROM npcs WHERE name LIKE '$search' LIMIT $rowsperpage OFFSET $offset ";
```

Please, note single quotes "around" $search and LIMIT is after WHERE.

Also, use prepared sql statements or mysql escape, the way you are doing this is perfect for SQL injection attack.

Comment: It is more readable to use the newer `LIMIT limit OFFSET offset` notation rather than the older `LIMIT offset, limit` one.

Answer (score 2):

The `LIMIT` clause goes after the `WHERE` clause.

[MySQL `SELECT` statement syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I've tried that. It still doesn't work.

Comment: It sounds like the variables you're putting into the SQL might not be strings. Or might be very large strings. Could you put more code in your example around the problematic statement?